# Adjusting precision recall curve for oversampling

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall, oversampling

I built a model for a binary target using oversampled data.
The population target prevalence is 0.25.
I oversampled to 0.5 by keeping the entirety of the minority class and sampling a portion of the majority class.
I then built a precision recall table using sklearn's:

```
#y is the binary target
#PR_CV are out of bag predictions
precision, recall, tr = precision_recall_curve(y, PR_CV)
```

I'd now want to know what precision and recall look like on the original population.
I tried implementing the following, based on [this](https://yiminwu.wordpress.com/2013/12/03/how-to-undo-oversampling-explained/) article:

```
#odds = p/(1-p)
odds = y.mean()/(1-y.mean())
print 'oversampled odds:',odds

original_fraction = 0.25
original_odds = original_fraction/ (1 – original_fraction)
print "original odds:",original_odds

#Scoring_odds = scoring_results / (1 – scoring_results)
scoring_results = PR_CV
print "probability to revert:", scoring_results
scoring_odds = scoring_results/(1-scoring_results)
print"scoring odds:", scoring_odds

#adjusted_odds = Scoring_odds * original_odds / oversampled_odds 
adjusted_odds = scoring_odds * original_odds / odds
print "adjusted odds:", adjusted_odds

#adjusted_probability = 1 / (1 + 1/adjusted_odds))
adjusted_probability = 1 / (1 + 1/adjusted_odds)
print "adjusted probability:", adjusted_probability
```

I then calculated:

```
precision_adj, recall_adj, tr_adj = precision_recall_curve(y, PR_CV_adj)
```

What this returns is the exact same values as `precision_recall_curve(y, PR_CV)`

That fails my intuition...What is the right way to do this?

The question I'm truing to answer is: if on an oversampled population I expect at the top 5th percentile to have x true positives over X predicted positives (precision), then on the entire population what are my x2 true positives and my X2 predicted positives?

Comment: Good news! Class imbalance is not a problem, and you did not need to undersample!
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/proper-scoring-rule-when-there-is-a-decision-to-make-e-g-spam-vs-ham-email
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he)

Answer (score 1):

Because the adjustment is a monotonic function, every threshold in the model's probability space has a corresponding one in the adjusted space (indeed, just apply the same adjustment) at which the confusion matrix of the resulting hard classifiers are the same. So the precision-recall curves are the same, it's just that every point corresponds to a different threshold.

Answer (score 0):

To estimate efficacy of using sampling techniques you should first split your data between train/test set, apply sampling on training data and then estimates results on test set. The way you are doing you can leakage information and get unrealistic performances results.